# Вывести значение в зависимости от условия?

Tags: javascript

**Задача:** если `a` больше чем `b` более чем на `10`, вывести `a + 10`; в ином случае, если `a` меньше чем `b`, вывести `9`; в ином случае `b`)

```
if (a > b && a > 10) {
    console.log(a + 10);
} else {
    console.log(a + 9);
}
```

Comment: `const f = (a, b) => a - 10 > b ? a + 10 : a < b ? 9 : b;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getNumber(a, b) {
   if (a - 10 > b) 
      return a + 10;

   if (a < b) 
      return 9;

   return b;
}

console.log(getNumber(12, 1)); // 22
console.log(getNumber(1, 11)); // 9
console.log(getNumber(12, 5)); // 5
```

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста почему а - 10 ?

Comment: @DmitryWalker "a больше чем b более чем на 10" означает, что если из `a` вычесть `10`, то полученное значение должно быть больше `b`. Можно записать и по-другому. `a > b + 10`.

Comment: Спасибо! теперь  понял

Comment: @DmitryWalker вот и отлично. Значит я не зря писал ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Если a больше чем b более чем на 10 (псевдокод)

```
(a - b > 10) -> a + 10
```

Eсли a меньше чем b

```
(a < b) -> 9
```